# Default to only showing 'Live' entries in CP?

Tags: control-panel, config

I'm finding that the structures view in CP is really slow with the amount of entries I have in it. The vast majority of these will be in draft for some time yet, however. I've had a look through the source of craft.js and hacked it a bit to just show the live entries by default just to see what would happen. The result is the CP is way more responsive in this view but obviously the status button doesn't reflect the right view any more and it's not a good idea to be doing this anyway.

Is there scope to make this configurable via a plugin or something?

Comment: There is a drop-down (to the left of the search field) to only show entries with a particular status (i.e. live), which is persistent when switching between channels, structures, etc. Is that not what your looking for?

Comment: I didn't realise it persisted if you stay in Entries, it does default back to 'All' if you navigate away though. I would like it to persist with 'Live' regardless. Minor quibble I know but it really is very slow.

Comment: FWIW, Craft 2.3 should fix the performance problem of Structures and Categories with large amounts of entries.

Answer (score 2):

I'm adding Brad's comment here as an answer as I think it addressed indirectly this issue:

```
Craft 2.3 should fix the performance problem of Structures and Categories with large amounts of entries.
```